# Gradle build memory issues with Chaquopy

Tags: python, android, gradle, chaquopy

I have an Android camera app and a separate Python image processing pipeline which I would like to integrate with the app using Chaquopy. However, the python code itself is large, and depends on about 50 modules, such as tensorflow,opencv,scikit-image,numpy and scipy among others. I can a run a toy python function on incoming frames from the camera app. However, I can't even build the full pipeline, because Gradle quits with the following error:

*Task :Application:generateDebugPythonRequirementsAssets*

*Task :Application:generateDebugPythonBuildAssets FAILED*

*Out of memory: Java heap space.
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.
For example, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:*

It fails either at "Application:generateDebugPythonRequirementsAssets" or at
"Application:generateDebugPythonBuildAssets", depending on how many modules are in requirememnts.txt

I have tried to increase heap space as suggested, up to 128 GB, but it didn't help.

How can I reduce the memory requirements to fit in some reasonable space?

**EDIT**

here's the pip block from build.gradle

```
pip {
    install "-r", "requirements.txt"
}
```

the requirements.txt is file has the following:

```
absl-py==0.9.0
ansicolors==1.1.8
astor==0.8.1
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.2
gast==0.2.2
google-auth==1.11.3
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
imageio==2.8.0
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
Markdown==3.2.1
matplotlib
networkx==2.4
nose==1.3.7
numpy
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
opt-einsum==3.2.0
Pillow==7.0.0
protobuf==3.11.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pyparsing==2.4.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyWavelets==1.1.1
requests==2.23.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.0
scikit-image==0.16.2
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.14.0
tensorboard==2.1.1
tensorflow==2.1.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.8
Werkzeug==1.0.0
wrapt==1.12.1
```

**EDIT**

Here's a full stack trace

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Application:generateDebugPythonBuildAssets'.
> Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:

org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Application:generateDebugPythonBuildAssets'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin.hashAssets(PythonPlugin.groovy:761)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin$hashAssets$15.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin.hashAssets(PythonPlugin.groovy:749)
    at com.chaquo.python.PythonPlugin$_createAssetsTasks_closure24$_closure61.doCall(PythonPlugin.groovy:679)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to give the full stack trace for the two Gradle errors. It would also be useful if you included the `pip` block from your build.gradle file.

Comment: Also, after editing the gradle.properties file, you might need to kill the Gradle daemon process so it'll be restarted on the next build.

Comment: I have edited the question as you requested. I'm not sure how to kill the gradle daemon. I'm using invalidate caches/restart in android studio. is that enough? Just to be on the safe side, I restarted the system. Nothing changed.

Comment: I think restarting Android Studio should be enough, but you might also want to check whether there are any other Java processes running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following to gradle.properties file

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16G

org.gradle.workers.max=1

Comment: Interesting: did you definitely need both of these, or is one of them enough on its own?

Comment: verified that org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx16G is enough.

Comment: The excessive memory use was fixed in Chaquopy version 7.0.3, so editing gradle.properties is no longer necessary on that version or newer.